# Setting each letter in page to a random color with JS. Why are there always an extra set of span tags before each opening tags of the page?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

[Page hosted with Google Drive](https://6f29293cc6046a4bab2dc1c345fd811216087ec6.googledrive.com/host/0B71AnQstJeptclRXR2dfd0FERU0/front.html)

The JS

```
var part_of_doc = false;  //a character has been found that is not part of the visible document
var body;

//will be used to generate random rgb
function randint(max, min) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
}
//generate a random rgb(x,y,z) string
function randRGB(){
    var color = "rgb(";
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        color += randint(0, 255).toString() + ",";
    }
    color = color.substring(0, color.length - 1);  //formatting the rgb to
    color += ')';  //be a proper rgb value

    return color;
}

//returns a character surrounded by a set of spans with a random background-color rgb value 
function spanify(char){
    var open_span = '<span style="color:' + randRGB() + '">';
    return open_span + char + '</span>';  //return the opening tag of a random color rgb tag, character, and a closing span
}

body = document.body.innerHTML;
for (var i=body.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    body = document.body.innerHTML;  //update body
    console.log(body[i], i);

    if (body[i] == ">") {  //the upcoming characters are part of an html tag and should be ignored
        part_of_doc = false;
        console.log(false);

    } else if (body[i] == "<") {  //the following characters may be part of the visible page and should not be ignored
        part_of_doc = true;
        console.log(true);

    } else if (part_of_doc == true && body[i] != " ") {  //found a character that is part of the visible page
        console.log("changing?");
        document.body.innerHTML = body.substring(0, i) + spanify(body[i]) + body.substring(i + 1, body.length);  //insert a span with a random color to the page surrounding a letter of the page
        console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

If you inspect element the page, you will see that before every opening tag that is not a direct child has a set of `span`s before it. The objective of the JS is to color each letter on the page randomly, so I would like to remove that glitch, although it is not critical as the objective is still completed. Can anyone tell why this is happening? I don't know why the algorithm would differentiate between open and closed tags, it should see them exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're coloring newlines - `"\n"` and possibly `"\r"` characters. Check that `body[i]` is not one of those before you spanify it:

```
else if (part_of_doc == true && body[i] != " " && body[i] != "\r" && body[i] != "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked.